# Updated pandas shows old version and throws attribute error when explode function is used

Tags: python, pandas

My pandas version was 0.23.4 but as I needed to use the explode function, I upgraded using

```
!pip3 install --upgrade pandas==0.25.0

Output shows: Successfully installed pandas-0.25.0
```

But when I used the explode function, it throws an `attribute error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'`.

I checked my pandas version using pd.**version** and the output shows 0.23.4, not the newly updated version.
Please point me out where I did wrong and help me accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: One idea - try restart PC.

Comment: It worked fine after doing a restart. Thanks!

Comment: Voting to close since the issue was fixed by a reboot.

Comment: @jezrael I think if some answer inside comment was correct then it needs to be posted as answer to be accepted, at least in short. Nice when all questions have accepted answers :). Instead of closing questions.